# Angular Observable subscribe method returns values out of order

Tags: angular, rxjs, observable

I'm working on Pokedex using PokeAPI. I recieve an array of pokemon evolutions which looks like this.

https://pokeapi-215911.firebaseapp.com/api/v2/evolution-chain/10

Then I'm trying to return a model by subscribing to another method to return the Pokemon sprites. My issue is that the subscribe method finishes in the wrong order so I end up with a chain that sometimes goes Venusaur > Bulbasaur > Ivysaur instead of Bulbasaur > Ivysaur > Venusaur. How can I get these in the correct order?

```
private loopThroughEvolutionChain(chain: any): any {
    let evoChain: PokemonEvolution[] = [];
    let evoData = chain.chain;
    let index: number = 1;

    do {
      let evoDetails = evoData['evolution_details'];

      this.getPokemonEvolutionDetails(evoData.species.name).subscribe((pkmn: any) => {
          evoChain.push(new PokemonEvolution(index, pkmn.name, pkmn.sprites.front_default, pkmn.sprites.front_shiny));
          index++;
      });

      evoData = evoData['evolves_to'][0];
    } while (!!evoData && evoData.hasOwnProperty('evolves_to'));

    return evoChain;
  }
```

Updated 11/4/19 with getPokemonEvolutionDetails

```
private getPokemonEvolutionDetails(name: string) {
    let apiUrl = `${this.apiBaseUrl}/pokemon/${name}`;

    return this._httpClient.get(apiUrl).pipe(
      map((response: any) => {
        return response;
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: Can you show what's inside `getPokemonEvolutionDetails`?

Comment: Hi @martin I've updated the questions with that method